# Directory with datetime+string key, and automatic removal of old entries

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have an application that receives certain "events", uniquely identified by a 12 chars string and a DateTime. At each event is associated a result that is a string.
I need to keep these events in memory (for a maximum of for example 8 hours) and be able, in case I receive a second time the same event, being able to know I've already received it (in the last 8 hours).
Events to store will be less than 1000.
I can't use an external storage, it has to be done in memory.

My idea is to use a Dictionary where the key is a class composed of a string and a datetime, the value is the result.

EDIT: the string itself (actually a MAC address) does not identify uniquely the event, it's the MAC AND the DateTime, those two combined are unique, that's why the key must be formed by both.
The application is a server that receives a certain event from a client: the event is marked on the client by client MAC and by the client datetime (can't use a guid).
It may happen that the client retransmits the same data, and by checking the dictionary for that MAC/Datetime key I would know that I have already received that data.

Then, every hour (for example), I can foreach through the whole collection and remove all the keys where datetime is older than 8 hours.

Can you suggest a better approach to the problem or to the data formats I have chosen? In terms of performance and cleaniness of the code.
Or a better way to delete old data, with LINQ for example.

Thanks,
Mattia

Comment: Do you mean Dictionary? Directory sounds like it *would* be using external storage.

Comment: oh god thanks... yes Dictionary of course...

Comment: Why do the string AND the datetime be unqiue? So in your collection the string can occur multiple times?

Comment: yes, I edited the question, the string is a MAC address, that identifies my client, that added to the datetime of the event generated on the client identifies globally my event (two events may have same time and different macs, and two events with same mac can't have same datetime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for a Dictionary.

This way you can searh very fast for the string (O(1)-operation).

Other collections are slower:

- OrderedDictionary: is slow because it needs boxing and unboxing.
- SortedDictionary: performs an O(log n) operation.
- All normal arrays and lists: use an O(n/2) operation.

An example:

```
public class Event
{
    public Event(string macAddress, DateTime time, string data)
    {
        MacAddress = macAddress;
        Time = time;
        Data = data;
    }

    public string MacAddress { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class EventCollection
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Tuple<string, DateTime>, Event> _Events = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, DateTime>, Event>();

    public void Add(Event e)
    {
        _Events.Add(new Tuple<string, DateTime>(e.MacAddress, e.Time), e);
    }

    public IList<Event> GetOldEvents(bool autoRemove)
    {
        DateTime old = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
        List<Event> results = new List<Event>();
        foreach(Event e in _Events.Values)
            if (e.Time < old)
                results.Add(e);

        // Clean up
        if (autoRemove)
            foreach(Event e in results)
                _Events.Remove(new Tuple<string, DateTime>(e.MacAddress, e.Time));

        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but at each event is associated a value, that I must store in the dictionary (I have three elements: string (MAC), datetime , string (value of the event)).
Also, with your Dictionary, how can I cleanup the Dictionary and remove all the DateTimes older than 8 hours?

Comment: Thanks so much for the written example, but as I stated in my previous comment I must deal with 3 elements in my Dictionary:
string (MAC), datetime AND another string that is the value of the event.
So my event can have "AABBCCDDEEFF", 2013-05-01T12:13:15, "value of the event".

With your solution, where can I store "value of the event"?
Thanks

Comment: Ah... going back to the drawing board! :)

Comment: For my information. You say MAC+DateTime are unique. Do you want to store them uniquely? Or will the event never occur on produce that duplicate date. With other words: Should the software check of duplicated and filter them out?

Comment: Yes are unique. Doesn't matter how are stored, I just need to know, if is the second time I receive that MAC+DateTime, and in that case get the value I received the first time.

Comment: Great thanks, I like the Tuple solution.
Regarding the removal of the old values, I'll compare your solution and Jon one to see which one performs best.

Comment: Please note that my solution combines the retrieval and removal of the old values. Jon's solution only does the retrieval, not the removal. Make sure your compare equal operations. Let me know the outcome. :)

Comment: I managed to work on this just now. Tuple solution fits nicely, but removal with linq is faster than your solution. Jon's solution actually does the removal, by keeping only recent (>=) dates.
I had to test with 10000000 entries to see the difference by the way...with 1000 it can't almost be detected. Thanks!

Comment: I can imagine that Jon's answer is faster if it comes down to removal. It also depends on the contents of the dictionary. If you have a dictionary of 1000 items and you just remove 10, removal would be easier. But, if you remove 990 of the 1000, then it would be faster to select those remaining 10 items and put them in a new dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

The event time has to **not** be part of the key -- if it is, how are you going to be able to tell that you have already received this event? So you should move to a dictionary where the keys are event names and the values are tuples of date and result.

Once in a while you can trim old data from the dictionary easily with LINQ:

```
dictionary = dictionary
    .Where(p => p.Value.DateOfEvent >= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-8))
    .ToDictionary();
```

Comment: I edited the question, maybe I've not been clear enough about why the datetime must be in the key.

Comment: Very nice solution to delete the old data, but in case I choose the Dictionary<Tuple<string, DateTime>, Event> solution to store the data, would it be possible to adapt your solution to check the DateTime in the Tuple key instead of p.Value.DateOfEvent?

Comment: @MattiaDurli: Sure -- `t => t.Item2.DateOfEvent >= ...`, or whatever item number you have decided to keep the date in.

Answer (score 1):

If requirements state that updating once per hour is good enough, and you're never having more than 1000 items in the dictionary, your solution should be perfectly adequate and probably the most easily understood by anyone else looking at your code.  I'd probably recommend immutable structs for the key instead of classes, but that's it.

If there's a benefit to removing them *immediately* rather than once per hour, you could do something where you also add a Timer that removes it after exactly 8 hours, but then you've got to deal with thread safety and cleaning up all the timers and such.  Likely not worth it.

I'd avoid the OrderedDictionary approach since it's more code, and may be slower since it has to reorder with every insert.

It's a common mantra these days to focus first on keeping code simple, only optimize when necessary.  Until you have a known bottleneck and have profiled it, you never know if you're even optimizing the right thing.  (And from your description, there's no telling which part will be slowest without profiling it).

Comment: OrderedDictionary approach would only be slower on an insert, (relativly) much faster when removing old events ;). But I agree, not worth it if the events don't come in order.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an OrderedDictionary where the key is the 12 charactor identifier and the result and datetime are part of the value. Sadly OrderedDictionary is not generic (key and value are objects), so you would need to do the casting and type checking yourself.  When you need to remove the old events, you can foreach through the OrderedDictionary and stop when you get to a time new enough to keep.  This assumes the datetimes you use are in order when you add them to the dictionary.

Comment: I edited the question, maybe I've not been clear enough about why the datetime must be in the key.
And no, datetimes of the event not necessarily will be in order.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I wouldn't use an OrderedDicationary then if the datetimes can come out of order. Like Dax said, this approach would require reordering after every insert and wouldn't save that much time if there are only 1000 or so events.